# what should I do with (Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I checked all questions about this title and I couldn't find a clear answer, when I my app I receive this error:

What went wrong:

> A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3.
> Searched in the following locations:
> Could not find com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10.
> Searched in the following locations.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

and my `build.gradle` looks it contain everything.Here is my buiild.gradle:

```js
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is my gradle-wrapper.properties:

```
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists 
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME 
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists 
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip
```

what should I do now?

Comment: is it react native app or Native android app?

Comment: Native android app

Comment: can you share gradle-wrapper.properties file too here

Comment: #Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-all.zip

Comment: Can you share the  build.gradle app also please

Comment: i added to the question

Comment: @Sara just now ?

Comment: @Sayooj the first code is the build.gradle

Comment: its build.gradle project right ? I asked for build.gradle app ...  @Sara

Answer (score 0):

I am able to build the newly created project with your configs.

```
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.31'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }

}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Can you please try this and let us know if it works?

Comment: I removed these just for testing
" allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
} "

Comment: @Sara any update if it works?

Comment: Thank yout , but i got the same errors